# Store data in array, object, struct, list or class. C#

Tags: c#, arrays, list, object, struct

I want to make a program that store `phones` like:

```
Brand:    Samsung
Type:     Galaxy S3
Price:    199.95
Ammount:  45
-------------------
Brand:    LG
Type:     Cookie
Price:    65.00
Ammount:  13
-------------------
etc, etc, etc,
```

What is the best practices to do that?
In `php` I should have done:

```
$phones = array(
    array(
        array("Brand"   => "Samsung"),
        array("Type"    => "Galaxy S3"),
        array("Price"   => 199.95),
        array("Ammount" => 45)
    ),
    array(
        array("Brand"   => "LG"),
        array("Type"    => "Cookie"),
        array("Price"   => 65.00),
        array("Ammount" => 13)
    )
)
```

Is this also possible in `C#`, because I dont know how many phones there are going in the list, and the datatypes are different: `string`, `decimal`, `int`.
I dont know what to use because you have `lists`, `structs`, `objects`, `classes` and so further.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use a class like:

```
public class Phone
{
    public string Brand { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public int Amount { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can fill a `List<Phone>`, for example with the [collection initializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx) syntax:

```
var phones = new List<Phone> { 
    new Phone{
        Brand = "Samsung", Type ="Galaxy S3", Price=199.95m, Amount=45
    },
    new Phone{
        Brand = "LG", Type ="Cookie", Price=65.00m, Amount=13
    } // etc..
};
```

... or in a loop with [`List.Add`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3wcytfd1(v=vs.110).aspx).

Once you've filled the list you can either loop it  to get one phone at a time

For example:

```
foreach(Phone p in phones)
    Console.WriteLine("Brand:{0}, Type:{1} Price:{2} Amount:{3}", p.Brand,p.Type,p.Price,p.Amount);
```

or you can use the list indexer to access a specific phone at a given index:

```
Phone firstPhone = phones[0]; // note that you get an exception if the list is empty
```

or via LINQ extension methods:

```
Phone firstPhone = phones.First(); 
Phone lastPhone  = phones.Last(); 
// get total-price of all phones:
decimal totalPrice = phones.Sum(p => p.Price);
// get average-price of all phones:
decimal averagePrice = phones.Average(p => p.Price);
```

Comment: Be proactive and add a string for additional data (special offers, rebates, html links, you name it)

Comment: @pe: i could add millions of other things like overriding `ToString` or `Equals`+`GetHashCode`, parsing from `string` or..or..or. But it would just distract from the essential. I think OP is clever enough to understand the concept.

Comment: It was no criticism, rather a suggestion to the OP. Your answer is close to perfect (no kidding).

Comment: Brand could be an enum, to avoid spelling mistakes.

Comment: @BCdotNET: and if you get a new brand/customer you have to recompile?

Comment: @ Tim: This entire question is about storing/hardcoding data in code, so that would be necessary anyway.

Comment: @BCdotNET: if `Brand` would be an enum, `Brand.Samsung` would be an enum-value. So if OP sometime had a brand `Sony` he has to modify the enum and recompile his project. That's something different as if you just have to add a new `Phone{ Brand = "Sony" ,... }`. Of course he could also create a class `Brand` or `PhoneManufacturer`.

Comment: Please tell me where is this saved ? If I close the application, am I supposed to be able to Load last data I "saved" as an object? Need serialization? Need DB? Need txt or binary file save? XML ?

Answer (score 4):

Best solution is to create your `Phone object` like:

```
public class Phone {
    public string Brand { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public decimal Ammount { get; set; }
}
```

and store this object in list (for example):

```
List<Phone> phones = new List<Phone> ();
phones.Add(new Phone { Brand = "Samsung", Type = "Galaxy S3", Price = 199.95, Amount = 45 });
etc
```

Answer (score 2):

You would have a model class, like

```
class Phone
{
     public string Brand  {get; set;}
     public string Type   {get; set;}
     public decimal Price {get; set;}
     public int Amount    {get; set;}
}
```

And then to create a list of the phones, you can use code like this

```
var phones = new List<Phone>
{
    new Phone{Brand = "Samsung", Type = "Galaxy S3", Price = 199.95, Amount = 45},
    new Phone{Brand = "LG",  Type = "Cookie", Price = 65.00, Amount = 13},
}
```

Comment: Structures can also do the job similarly as explained in other answers and list(array) can be used as collection of objects

Comment: @AliKazmi Structures as `struct` can be used, but that will be a poor choice. `Phone` data type is more like a `class` in C# terms. Not sure what's your point anyway.